# Listing unscheduleable kubernetes nodes by taints in operator-sdk/client-go

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I am trying to list all the nodes that are set to unscheduleable in an operator-sdk operator. Generally (pre 1.12) this means they have `spec.unscheduleable` set. So I tried this:

```
nodes := &corev1.NodeList{}
opts := &client.ListOptions{}
if err := opts.SetFieldSelector("spec.unschedulable=true"); err != nil {
  reqLogger.Info("Failed to set field selector")
}
```

Which is erroring:

```
2019-04-23T10:19:39.761-0700    ERROR   kubebuilder.controller  Reconciler error    {"controller": "node-controller", "request": "/nodename", "error": "Index with name field:spec.unschedulable does not exist"}
```

I'm confused about this because the field selector works from kubectl:

```
kubectl get nodes --field-selector="spec.unschedulable=true"
```

Alongside this issue, I have noticed that after v1.12, the spec.unscheduleable field has been [deprecated](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69010) in favour of TaintNodeByCondition. This further complicates things, because now I really don't think I can use the fieldselector anyone, because I don't believe (unless I'm mistaken?) that you can use fieldselector with the taints anyway.

So, my question is - how can I list all of the tainted/unscheduleable nodes in my cluster efficiently, specifically when using the operator-sdk

UPDATE:

I have managed to solve the fieldselector problem by using a v1meta.ListOptions call, like so:

```
nodes := &corev1.NodeList{}
opts := &client.ListOptions{
Raw: &metav1.ListOptions{
  FieldSelector: "spec.unschedulable=true",
  },
}
```

However, I still don't know how to do this with taints, so I've edited the question and will leave it open

Answer (score 1):

I'm using client-go APIs and I've also struggled with this issue, so I did a workaround which I'm not sure whether this is the best option or not. Nevertheless, will share my code.

It starts with gettings all the nodes then filtering the ones that do not have taints.

```
func GetNodes(withoutTaints bool, clientset kubernetes.Interface, ctx 
*context.Context, options *metav1.ListOptions) *v1.NodeList {
    nodes, err := clientset.CoreV1().Nodes().List(*ctx, *options)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if withoutTaints {
        nodesWithoutTaints := v1.NodeList{}
        for _, node := range nodes.Items {
            if len(node.Spec.Taints) == 0 {
                nodesWithoutTaints.Items = append(nodesWithoutTaints.Items, node)
            }
        }
        return &nodesWithoutTaints
    }
    return nodes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Controller Runtime docs, using raw options won't work well with the cache.

Instead you should add the desired fields to the index during controller initialization:

```
idx := myManager.GetFieldIndexer()
idx.IndexField(&corev1.Node{}, "spec.unschedulable", func(o runtime.Object) []string {
    return []string{fmt.Sprintf("%v", o.(*corev1.Node).Spec.Unschedulable)}
})
```

I don't know if this can help you with the Operator SDK though.